# Native USB Debugging on Chrome 32 doesn't detect device

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. With the release of Chrome 32, I wanted to try the native usb debugging so I could work with my phonegap apps while they're on my phone (rather than browser testing then transferring). I turned on USB debugging and downloaded the appropriate driver. My phone shows up in device manager but it doesn't show up under about:inspect on chrome. How do I get my device to show up?

Answer (score 63):

I had a similar issue. I was previously able to inspect my phone using DevTools and the ADB extension. After the Chrome update where the ADB extension was deprecated my phone would no longer appear in chrome://inspect/ not matter what I tried.

What fixed the issue for me:

1. Download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download)
2. Locate ADB.exe, found in the platform-tools folder.
3. Open the file using command prompt

   cd c:\path\to\platform-tools\adb.exe
4. Make sure your phone is disconnected from USB
5. Type the following commands

   adb devices

   adb kill-server

   adb start-server
6. Reconnect your phone, authorise your PC and enjoy the USB debugging

Hopefully that helps someone else.

Comment: I tried a lot of things but only this one really helped. Thanks

Comment: I have this problem pretty often. Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: I ended up creating a shortcut on my desktop: Right click on desktop > New > Shortcut > and enter adb.exe's location (you can use Find to find it) plus 'devices'. Mine looks like 'C:\Users\myusername\cminstaller\bundle\win32\adb.exe devices'

Comment: Additionally I had to check for the Device Driver & Associate the Driver (google\usb_driver\) from the ../extras/ folder to my Device

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: Same answer, but with more details is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24410867/1343917

Comment: Just wanted to say THANKS to tenderloin. Nothing else worked! Also, deer venison is awesome-- love a fresh tenderloin.

Comment: My god thank you. This was the only thing that worked for me after a 1.5 days of troubleshooting. I _wanted_ to avoid downloading the IDE, but that's truly the only option on PC.

Comment: Thank you, I always forget the "adb devices" step (as well as the current location of the android-sdk due to the MotoDev->Eclipse+AndroidSdk->Android Studio->Xamarin churn).

Answer (score 16):

I found the solution. I'd never run ADB before but that's what Chrome uses for debugging (not sure if it was downloaded when I downloaded the dev kit or if it came with Chrome 32).

From the command line I ran, adb devices. Got the message "daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037". Once it started, my device showed up in Chrome! If you haven't downloaded the android dev kit you may have to do that first.

Comment: Your procedure fixed it for me (Chrome v32 on Win7). Thanks. I had to start it as follows because adb.exe is not in the Path. WIN>cd c:\apps\adtwin\sdk\platform-tools\   WIN> adb devices

Comment: Hey @William Neely, this works but when I inspect something I have a blank window - http://prntscr.com/5dresg

Answer (score 1):

You need Chrome on Android Beta (v32) to do this without ADB.

Comment: Additional info: Chrome beta is a separate app from Chrome.

Comment: I'm running Android Beta (v33) on devices and Chrome Beta (v33) and Chrome Canary (v34) on the Windows 8.1, but remote USB debugging does not work with any of my devices (S2, S3, Galaxy Tab 10.1).  I'm using latest Samsung USB driver 2.11.   Works in Android Studio with all devices, but Chrome about:inspect shows "No Devices Detected". Tried revoking USB authorizations as suggested in wiki, but no go. So I'm wondering if the feature is stable.  Maybe a Windows issue?

Comment: PS: this also works for me if I run the ADB daemon prior to trying USB debugging.

Comment: Same experience here with Chrome 41 (Windows desktop and Android). Does not work without ADB active, despite the documentation clearly stating it is independent of ADB