# Can you inspect element on a Samsung tablet's default Internet application

Tags: samsung-mobile, web-inspector

Is there any way of inspecting element on a Samsung tablet using the default Internet Application? I have some bugs that need sorting that only appear in the native Samsung / Android 'Internet' application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Samsung Internet](http://developer.samsung.com/internet) can be debugged remotely using Chrome on the desktop. Any pages you have open in Samsung Internet should be listed for inspection under `chrome://inspect`:

[image: Screenshot]

As [Ada shared here](https://medium.com/@Lady_Ada_King/hi-brian-this-is-how-i-do-remote-debugging-294b286009f9#.vaxey16x3), you can also enable port forwarding and connect to a server running on your desktop machine. You will need the Chrome app running on your desktop. If your localhost URL does not resolve, visit `chrome://inspect` and ensure port forwarding is enabled. You may also need to open the Chrome app on your mobile device.

Update: There is [a page in the Dev Hub docs about remote debugging here](https://hub.samsunginter.net/Docs/remote-debugging).

Comment: I can connect to a Galaxy tablet and it's listed in the devices tab of the 'chrome://inspect' page, but there's no list of pages to inspect on that tab. I've gone to the 'pages' tab and clicked inspect on those, but in dev tools, none of the output on the 'elements' tab looks like the page I have open in the Samsung Internet app on the tablet. Any advice?

Comment: @moosefetcher Please could you share which version of Samsung Internet it is? Also just to check, do you have the Chrome app open on your mobile device too? (It can be necessary to establish the connection). Can you see pages you have open in Chrome listed?

Comment: The Internet app version is 4.2.2; I've now got Chrome and Internet open on the tablet. It looks like the tablet page is listed now!

Comment: Unchecking css rules doesn't seem to have any effect on the tablet. Should it? And how do I even tell if I'm looking at the page through 'Internet' or Android Chrome? Thanks for the help, btw!

Comment: Sorry unfortunately CSS can't be changed dynamically in v4. (It's resolved in v5! https://twitter.com/poshaughnessy/status/827536992888041472)
If you inspect via the Devices page, you should know whether it's Internet or Chrome because Internet pages will be listed under a 'com.sec.android.app.sbrowser' heading?

Comment: This did not work for me initially, I had to also follow the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410867/557406

Comment: The dev hub link is dead and this isn't working for me