# How to webkit-inspect the Samsung Browser on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

My Android (4.4.2) ships two browsers: chrome and 'The Appplication Called Internet'. Using chrome://inspect, I can remotely debug Chrome on the phone in Chrome on my computer, like this
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Is there a way to do the same with The Appplication Called Internet ?

Comment: Actually the app is called the Samsung Browser. Looking at a Galaxy S5 mini. Afaics its a webkit browser though.

Comment: It seems that the best you can do with Samsung Browser is to turn on a JavaScript console in it: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=258454

Comment: Not allowed to mark this as a duplicate or replicate the answer here, but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893299/can-you-inspect-element-on-a-samsung-tablets-default-internet-application/39275324