# How to debug a script that fails in Samsung Browser Chromium?

Tags: javascript, chromium

I have a javascript image gallery that works in all desktop browsers with no errors. For some reason it fails in the standard browser that ships with Samsung phones which is called Chromium - not Chrome.

I have downloaded the Chromium emulator and my script works fine in the emulator but still fails in the real browser.

Seeing as the real browser is on my phone and it has no debug console how can I trace execute the script to see where it fails?

Comment: do you see an error message somewhere? can you enable error log on your application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you inspect element on a Samsung tablet's default Internet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893299/can-you-inspect-element-on-a-samsung-tablets-default-internet-application)