# Testing samsung internet default phone default browser

Tags: samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

does anyone know how I can debug and see a console etc etc for Samsung's default browser on mobile devices?

(if you're going to say browserstack, please direct me to where on their site it says this as I've tried and as far as I can see it's chrome or firefox only for most of their device types)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an actual device with Samsung Internet on it (currently available on the Play Store and Galaxy Apps store for Samsung Galaxy or Pixel/Nexus devices), you can [remote debug it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893299/can-you-inspect-element-on-a-samsung-tablets-default-internet-application/39275324#39275324).

If you don't have a device, it was available on Browserstack when I checked a few months ago - but it's not currently on the free plan by the looks of it and we would need to confirm if they still offer it on their paid plans. When I checked, it was also available on other cloud device labs like TestObject. There's also Samsung's own [Remote Device Lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action). (For reference, there's a brief section [here under "What if I don't have a Samsung phone?"](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/introducing-samsung-internet-for-developers-6c3a3be42f72#c97f)).

This [Rough Guide](https://gist.github.com/poshaughnessy/5718717a04db20a02e9fdb3fc16e2258) includes some example device types from the Remote Device Lab that offer specific versions of Samsung Internet (last time I checked) if you want to test older ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good information there.

I've had demos from BRowserstack and TestObject / SauceLabs and to me TestObject is the best thing I can see for debugging on devices. It's expensive though.

The first remote debugging tip you've given me has helped a lot.