# Remote debugging the Samsung Internet App

Tags: html, remote-debugging, samsung-galaxy, chrome-remote-debugging

I've recently managed to get a desktop development machine to recognise a connected Samsung Galaxy Tab for remote debugging.
The html bug I'm trying to inspect and, hopefully, fix is a layout issue that occurs only in the pre-loaded Samsung 'Internet' app on the Galaxy tablet.
I've found this page...
https://samsunginter.net/docs/remote-debugging
... which has the following set of simple instructions for remote debugging the app:

1.Connect your mobile device to your desktop computer via a USB cable. If you are shown an “Allow access to device data” prompt, choose “Allow”.

2.Open up the Chrome browser on your desktop and visit chrome://inspect.

3.Check that your mobile device is listed. If it is not, you may need to open the Chrome app on your mobile device.

4.Any pages you have open in Samsung Internet should be **listed here for inspection**.

I'm fine up until step 4. The tablet is connected and listed but I don't see any pages 'listed here for inspection'. I have checked all of the tabs on the left-hand side of the chrome://inspect page - I've even enabled port forwarding, but I don't know if that's the correct thing to do.

Has anyone had experience of remote debugging the Samsung Internet App? What am I missing here that's preventing me from inspecting the html remotely?

Comment: I wrote that guide, so I'm keen to help get to the bottom of this :) I left you a reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893299/can-you-inspect-element-on-a-samsung-tablets-default-internet-application/39275324?noredirect=1#comment77348566_39275324