# Chrome devTools no longer seeing USB devices for debugging

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector, nexus-5

Yesterday, I plugged in my Nexus 5 to do some inspecting for mobile web development like I do on almost a daily basis.  When I went to "chrome://inspect", there was an exclamation point saying I needed to update chrome and wouldn't allow me to inspect any devices until I did so (It had been working fine just a few days before).

So, I let it upgrade to chrome on my desktop to 39.0.2171.65.  After the update, I went to chrome://inspect, and lo and behold, I get the dreaded "No devices detected...".  So, I go through a whole process of unplugging the phone from USB, revoking USB authorizations, completely reinstalling chrome on my desktop, reinstalling the USB driver, trying two different cables etc.  Still, "No devices detected...".  Yesterday, my phone just upgraded to Lollipop and still "No devices detected...".

Today, I restored my phone to factory settings.  Still "No Devices detected..."
I tried Chrome Canary.  Same results.

I don't know what else to do.  I even tried it on a different laptop using Windows 7 (using windows 8.1 on the other machine).  I don't know why this would all of the sudden stop working.

Comment: This answer worked for me [Chrome's remote debugging (USB debugging) not working for Samsung Galaxy S3 running android 4.3][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648230/chromes-remote-debugging-usb-debugging-not-working-for-samsung-galaxy-s3-runn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved on stable-channel (39.0.2171.95) and beta-channel (version 40.0.2214.28).

Comment: Are we supposed to be able to get any of the patches/fixes that they talk about in the string?  Or do we have to wait until an update comes out?

Comment: The issue has been fixed in recent Chrome Canary builds and will be released in the next dev-channel and beta-channel build. I cannot provide an ETA on a stable-channel fix.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm up and running again with canary until regular chrome gets the update.

Comment: How come in this new version you can't click on elements in the inspector for devices? You can only change which element you're inspecting with the arrow keys? Wtf?

Answer (score 13):

I just launched an "adb devices" in cmd, it started daemon, detected my device (nexus 5, andorid 5.0) and now chrome inspect tool works well

Comment: this just solved it for me - after upgrading to lollipop, chrome did not detect my nexus 5 anymore.