# White Screen of Death - Ionic 2 on Android

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

My app runs completely fine in the browser but when I run it on my device, I get this error:

```
 0     758771   log      deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
 1     758797   log      Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
 2     758932   error    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined, http://(ip address)/build/js/Reflect.js, Line: 894
```

Here's the code in `Reflect.js`, but this is something provided by Ionic's packaging, I can't change the code so I don't know how to fix this.

```
function CreateUUID() {
    var data = GenRandomBytes(UUID_SIZE);
    // mark as random - RFC 4122 § 4.4
    data[6] = data[6] & 0x4f | 0x40;
    data[8] = data[8] & 0xbf | 0x80;
    var result = "";
    for (var offset = 0; offset < UUID_SIZE; ++offset) {
        var byte = data[offset];
        if (offset === 4 || offset === 6 || offset === 8)
            result += "-";
            if (byte < 16)
                result += "0";
            result += byte.toString(16).toLowerCase();
        }
    return result;
}
```

It seems `GenRandomBytes()` is returning null here. Can someone help please?

Comment: Have you looked at the Javascript console with remote debugging either on [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en) for Android or Safari for [iOS](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/)?

Comment: @Lightbeard I tried the chrome//:inspect and the device is showing up but I can't interact with it. There's usually an "inspect" button under the device name at the chrome://inspect link. But not in my case, is there something I'm doing wrong there also? Sorry I'm new to Ionic and Android

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes the case that errors like that in Android Studio's logcat can be ignored. I have a feeling you will find the real problem if you can see it from Chrome's web tools.

Debugging Android from Chrome can be kind of finicky, take a look at:
[Chrome's remote debugging (USB debugging) not working for Samsung Galaxy S3 running android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648230/chromes-remote-debugging-usb-debugging-not-working-for-samsung-galaxy-s3-runn)

Specifically:

> I was developing for android using Android Studio. So I had almost
>   everything installed but Chrome didn't show me the list of devices.
>   The solution was to find adb.exe which was already on my PC, and to
>   run adb.exe devices. That did the trick for me. – Saeed Neamati

Once you have your app inspected and viewable in web tools, I recommend pressing **Ctrl+R** to refresh and view any Javascript/HTML/CSS errors captured during page load.